# Change color of balloons and text in Message.app

Tags: macos, messages, customization

In previous versions of Message.app bundled with Mac OS X, we could change the font and color of the message balloons. In Yosemite I no longer can find such options.

Am I simply failing to find the options? Is such customizing no longer allowed? If not allowed, is there any easy hacking tricks to get the same effect?

[image: screen shot of Messages.app]

Answer (score 1):

In OSX Yosemite colors are blue (for iMessages) and green (for SMS). There is no longer the ability to change these; Macs now look like iOS devices.

**Hard way: (backup first!)**

For Yosemite modify CSS here:

```
/System/Library/Messages/PlugIns/Balloons.transcriptstyle/Contents/Resources/balloons-modern.css
```

For El Captain it's now located in:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SocialUI.framework/Versions/A/Resources
```

But one needs to either disable rootless mode or to use a union file system mount to map the file over without rootless.

Hope this will help.

Comment: What about Catalina?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this!! You have to go into Accessibility options, Reduce Transparency, and then the options are back in the Messages preferences pane.